# how to configure rsyslog to receive log from specic IP addresses?

Tags: server, rsyslog

I want to configure rsyslog on a server so that receive logs from specific IP addresses and drop the others.is it possible?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://serverfault.com/questions/400293/syslog-ip-ranges-to-specific-files-using-rsyslog

Answer (score 0):

Block it with your UFW (assuming 1.1.1.1 is the device generating syslogs and 2.2.2.2 is your server)

sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw allow from 1.1.1.1 to 2.2.2.2 port 514/udp

check with

sudo ufw status